# Find the probability density function of Y= min{X, 1 − X }.

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose we have $X$, a $\operatorname{Uniform}(0, 1)$ random variable which follows with the probability density function $f_X (x)$. Let $Y = \min\{X, 1 − X \}$. It wasn't asked but I want to find the pdf of $Y$.

I think I know how to deal with other transformations but the min here is really bothering me (since $\min(X)=X$ when $X$ is less then $0.5$ maybe I tried to investigate two cases for $Y$ ( $Y$ less then or equal to $0.5$ and greater then $0.5$) but I'm stuck.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There may be more elegant arguments (based on, say, symmetry). Here is one simply doing the bruteforce thing: compute the PDF via the CDF.*

Consider the CDF of $Y$, $F$. For $y\in[0,1/2]$,
$$\begin{align*}
F(y) &= \mathbb{P}\{ Y \leq y\} =  \mathbb{P}\{ \min(X,1-X) \leq y\}
=  \mathbb{P}\{ X \leq y\}\cup \{ 1-X \leq y\} \\
&=  \mathbb{P}\{ X \leq y\}\cup \{ X \geq 1-y\} \\
&=\mathbb{P}\{ X \in (0,y]\cup[1-y,1)\}
\end{align*}$$
and since $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, this gives
$$
F(y) = 2y.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
F(y) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } y < 0\\
2y & \text{ if } y \in [0,1/2]\\
1 & \text{ if } y > 1/2\\
\end{cases}
$$
Differentiating the CDF, you get the PDF, call it $f$:
$$
f(y) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } y < 0\\
2 & \text{ if } y \in [0,1/2]\\
0 & \text{ if } y > 1/2\\
\end{cases}
$$
That is, $\boxed{Y\sim\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1/2)}$.

Comment: I don't really get why this : $$\begin{align*}
F(y) &= \mathbb{P}\{ Y \leq y\} =\mathbb{P}\{ X \in (0,y]\cup[1-y,1)\}
\end{align*}$$
gives us
F(y) = 2y.

Comment: @Studentnumberx Which part do you not understand in what you quoted? The last? If so, just note that the measure *under the uniform distribution* of $(0,y]$  is $y$, and so is the measure of $[1-y,1)$, and the two intervals are disjoint. (Or, if $y=1/2$, their intersection is $\{1/2\}$, which has measure 0)

Comment: Can density equal to more than 1? isn't the whole integral supposed to be equal to 1?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Yes, it can. Integrate 2 over [0,1/2], you will get 1.